# Why swift protocol use func overloading instead on func with different names?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

Just started to learn swift and noticed that protocol UICollectionViewDelegate (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate) 
has around 20 functions with the same name but different parameters. 
In C# we use overloads as well but we use them in case we want to do something similar like:

- GetUser(int id)
- GetUser(string userName)

but in swift we use the same func name for functions that do absolutely different things like:

- func collectionView(UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath)
- func collectionView(UICollectionView,
  targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset: CGPoint)

So the question is, why they don't use funcs like:

- func didSelect(UICollectionView, ItemAt: IndexPath)
- func targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(UICollectionView,
  offset: CGPoint)

in this case func name actually tells us what it's going to do and it's easier to find function you need

If there is some documentation why such a decisions were made I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: An essential part of showing the semantics and intent of a method in Swift to include it not only in the naming of the method but also of its function parameters. So the examples you list above abide the common naming convention used in Swift, which may seem unfamiliar at first, if you come from another language which use other conventions. See e.g. [the API design guidelines for _Naming_](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in swift the function name is actually broken up to be next to each param that the name is describing. This convention has it's roots in objective-c.

So those functions you showed above actually do have different names, the names is just broken up.

So

```
collectionView(UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath)
```

is collectionView:*didSelectItemAt:*

```
func collectionView(UICollectionView, targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset: CGPoint)
```

is collectionView:_ targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:_

It's a very descriptive naming convention. Just remember that the function's name is split up to be next to each parameter that the piece of the name is describing.

Comment: To expand on this: Objective-C doesn't allow a label for the first argument, so the first argument's label is lumped into the function name. Since the first argument of these delegate methods was a collection view, it made sense to just call the function `collectionView`. Since Swift supports labels for the first argument separate from the function name, you would never write an API like this in Swift. But these functions are imported from Objective-C as-is, so that's how they end up in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with how Objective C work, if you write these functions as selectors, it will be something like `"collectionView:didSelectItemAt:"`. Which implicitly tell you that it has something to do with collectionView, and won't confuse with `"tableView:didSelectItemAt:"`.

On the other hand if the function named `"didSelect:itemAt:"`, it does not provide any hints on what's the first parameter, it can be tableView, collectionView, or anything else, since objective c does not support overload, this will become a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow this example but looks like in your case one class implements two protocols, one for collectionView and one for tableView, and in the same class you have to use selectors so thanks to swift naming conventions it's easier for you to do this. If that is the case than it brakes SOLID Single responsibility principle. I mean if you separated table and collection objects you won't have problem with specifying selectors at all.

Comment: @IhorBats It's not about easier, Objective C is a language that first compile  to C before compile to binary, hence overloading is fundamentally impossible, calling all Objective C methods are in fact sending a message to an object, with the message that is a selector, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html).

Comment: @IhorBats Also has something to do with programming style, in iOS it is very common to have a ViewController confirms to multiple protocols. Yes this break SOLID but in Objective C there's some really good reason to do so: 
Objective C msg passing is always dynamic, means whenever you send a message to another class is quite some extra overhead.  Nevertheless, in the days before ARC, you have to manually retain and release objects being used, which make having a few different classes and instances in a VC very hard to work with, especially when objective C does not support nested class.

Comment: Thanks for additional info!